# Using numeric variable in where clause of ArcPy SearchCursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, where-clause

I know this question has been answered but I am not seeing an adaptation that I can understand. I am trying to use a numeric variable in a where clause and just having a hard time figuring it out.

```
fc1 = "L:\ENGINEERING\collind\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\sedaSampleHistory"

fieldname = "pocid"

delimfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc1, fieldname)

pocidCnt = 3

cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, ["pocid", "cl2total"], delimfield + " = pocidCnt ")
```

I have tried all kinds of ways to get pocidCnt to work in the where clause and I am not having any luck. If I write it as

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, ["pocid", "cl2total"], delimfield + " = 3 ")
```

it works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried not passing it as a string in quotes and just putting the variable name with no quotes:-------cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, ["pocid", "cl2total"], delimfield + pocidCnt )

Comment: Thanks for the quick response... when I make that change I get 

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code fails because the variable name (`pocidCnt`) is inside a string and is therefore being taken literally: the final query being used is `"pocid" = pocidCnt`, where `pocidCnt` is clearly not a number that can be matched. You can substitute the *value* represented by the `pocidCnt` variable into the query string in the following ways:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, ["pocid", "cl2total"], delimfield + " = " + str(pocidCnt))
```

or, preferably:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, ["pocid", "cl2total"], "{0} = {1}".format(delimfield, pocidCnt))
```

Comment: Thank you. Both of those work. So I guess what I was trying to do was insert an int into an expression that is a string. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the value of `pocidCnt` must be converted from an int to a string (i.e. from `3` to `"3"`) before it can be combined with the rest of the query string. The `str()` function achieves this clumsily, while the string `.format()` method is a little more graceful about it.